# ngFor with modal window for each item in correct order for screen reader

Tags: accessibility, angular8, ngfor, screen-readers, nvda

Having issues with the screen reading order after dialog modal window is open. Have a set of button tiles and when one is clicked a popup occurs. The tiles are used with ngFor and then modal box comes after. When you tab to the tile and click enter then use the down arrow it wont read the dialog box until after the last tile. Is there any way to insert the dialog box after each ngFor item? I have tried a few things, but nothing is working for me.

[www.bsca.com/fad](http://www.bsca.com/fad)

```
<button
     role="button"
     *ngFor="let grid of grids; let i = index"
     [ngClass]="getTileClassName()"
     [class.selected]="selected_type === grid.title"
     (click)="selectProvider($event, grid, wcmtpl)"
     (keyup)="handleTabIndexForGrid($event)"
     type="button"
     class="button-grid-item"
     aria-haspopup="true"
     aria-expanded="false"
     [attr.id]="grid.value"
     (keydown)="onGridSelect(grid.title)">
         <span class="label-wrap">
            <span (keydown)="handleTabIndexForGrid($event)" class="button-grid-label">
               {{ grid.title }}
            </span>
          </span>
</button>

<div
   #memberConfirmModal
   role="dialog"
   (onfocusout)="closePopupOnFocusout($event)"
   (keyup)="closePopup($event)"
   id="memberConfirmModal"
   autofocus
   z-index="9999"
   aria-hidden="false"
   [class.show]="selected_type"
   [ngStyle]="alert_style"
   tabindex="-1">
            <button
              #closeButtonModal
              class="close close-button-margin"
              (keydown)="onShiftTabFocusChange($event, noMbrLogin)"
              aria-label="Close dialog popup"
              tabindex="0"
            >
            </button>
            <div id="confirmDialog" class="wrapper">
              <fieldset class="mb-2">
                <legend class="mb-2">
                  <span tab-index="0" class="body-regular" #messageConfirmation>
                    {{ "bsc_member" | langtranslate }}
                    <span class="sr-only"
                      >{{ "Note" | langtranslate }}:
                      {{ "choosing_a_provider" | langtranslate }}
                    </span
                  >
                  </span>
                </legend>
                <button
                  role="button"
                  (click)="goTo(false)"
                  aria-hidden="false"
                  type="button"
                  #mbrLogin
                  id="mbrLogin"
                  tabindex="0"
                  class="btn-sm btn-primary inline"
                  gtm-track-click="{'eventCategory': 'Find a Doctor','eventAction': 'Authentication','eventLabel': 'Authentication Prompt: Yes I am a member','eventNonInteraction': 'false','event': 'eventTracker'}"
                >
                  {{ "yes" | langtranslate }}
                </button>
                <button
                  role="button"
                  (click)="goTo(true)"
                  aria-hidden="false"
                  (keydown)="handleKeyEventsForNO($event)"
                  (blur)="onTabFocusChange($event, closeButtonModal)"
                  type="button"
                  id="nonMember"
                  tabindex="0"
                  #noMbrLogin
                  class="btn-sm btn-primary inline"
                  gtm-track-click="{'eventCategory': 'Find a Doctor','eventAction': 'Authentication','eventLabel': 'Authentication Prompt: No I am not a member','eventNonInteraction': 'false','event': 'eventTracker'}"
                >
                  {{ "no" | langtranslate }}
                </button>
              </fieldset>
              <p class="mb-0">
                <span id="confirmDialogNote" aria-hidden="true" hidden
                  >{{ "note_text" | langtranslate }}
                  {{ "choosing_a_provider" | langtranslate }}
                  {{ "press_tab" | langtranslate }}</span
                >
                <span class="text-uppercase">{{ "note" | langtranslate }}</span>
                {{ "choosing_a_provider" | langtranslate }}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It appears that "autofocus" is only firing when you press the `tab` key. As such the screen reader still thinks it should continue reading from the current point. (You can see this behaviour by clicking an item with mouse and then pressing tab, it momentarily focuses the next button in the list before jumping into the modal.). Also pressing `space` opens the modal the same as a click, no focus is received. Change your function so that focus is automatically added to the modal close button no matter how it is accessed and this should fix the issue across the board.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance on this. I implemented that. I believe it is working correctly now.